# how to query by just giving genre information

Tags: python, movie, imdbpy

I want to get movies according to genre information by using imdbpy. I found IMDb.get_keyword function but it did not work for me. Any idea?

Example:

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
print ia.get_keyword(u'ring', results = 5)
```

Comment: By `doesn't work`, is there an error? Or it doesn't print anything?

Comment: Sorry. I did not explain clearly. Output of the IMDb.get_keyword function is not useful for me. What I need is a list of movies whose genre are same of my given argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind any proxy?

In that case, you might need to set_proxy.

```
i.set_proxy('http://yourhttproxyurl:proxyport/')
```

And then just use search_keyword to search for movies which might match a particular keyword for genre

```
import imdb
ia = imdb.IMDb()
t_result = ia.search_keyword(u'comedy')
// process your list of t_result
```

Comment: This is not the case of proxy or any connection problem. Output of the get_keyword is not relevant for me. search_movie is also useless because what I need is a list of movies whose genre are the same. I need a function  (like get_keyword(keyword, results)) or solution that is able to return specific number of movies whose genre are the same.

Comment: I think you just have to use the search_keyword and give it your genre name and then filter those movies. I don't see a direct interface available for searching by genre only.

Comment: It didn't work. First of all, search_keyword function returns "plot keywords", not movie (more precisely, movie object). Maybe you mean get_keyword function. But it didn't work as well. There is a movie named Black Swan. Imdb says that Black Swan's genres are drama and thriller. I used get_keyword(u'thriller') but I couldn't obtain any movie. I think there is an another way... By the way, thank you so much for attention Senthil.